# Multiple executable from same iPhone/XCode4 project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4, target

How do I create multiple executables from the same XCode4 project? I tried to create several targets with different names on the executable, but it always overwrite the existing app and change name on it instead of create a new executable...

Answer (score 1):

on the left. where you see your project. If you select it, your main window will display a sort of properties window. In there you can press the Add Target button on the bottom left.

Hope that helps

Comment: I`ve allready added two targets with different executable names :/